# How to generate a $ 9 \times 9 $ matrix like Sudoku ？

Tags: matrix

i want to generate a matrix that the number in each row, colum contains 1-9,and not repeated.
my code always fall into no solution. here is my code.

```
orix = RandomSample[Range[1, 9]];
oriy = Join[{orix[[1]]}, 
   RandomSample[DeleteCases[Range[1, 9], orix[[1]]]]];
matrix = ConstantArray[0, {9, 9}];
matrix[[1]] = oriy;
matrix[[;; , 1]] = orix;
matrix // MatrixForm
Do[matrix[[x, y]] = 
  RandomChoice[
   Range[0, 9] /. 
    Thread[Flatten[{matrix[[x]], matrix[[;; , y]]}] -> Nothing]], {x, 
  2, 9}, {y, 2, 9}]; matrix // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Not sure it solves your problem, but did you see/review http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sudoku.html and http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5690/ and https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sudoku#Mathematica

Comment: Thanks it is what i want .The problem is more difficult than I imagined

Comment: For solving Sudoku, see [this](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2018/01/a-beginners-guide-to-solving-sudoku-puzzles-by-computer/)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score -1):

Thanks mr Moo ,Namjoshi ,and mikado 
the eligible matrix is much more than i thought.
we can get a example matrix by:

```
matrix = ConstantArray[0, {9, 9}];
k = RotateRight[Range[9], 1];
Do[k = RotateLeft[k, 1];matrix[[i]] = k, {i, 9}]
matrix // MatrixForm
```

the other matrix can be got by changing the position of two numbers
forexample `/.{1->9,9->1}`

Comment: I do not see how this answers your question. Sudoku matrices are divided in 9 smaller matrices and they should have all numbers different.